# Relate names with Id's

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, equality

I'm trying to relate some Ids with names as the image below:

[image]

Basically I would like to create a relation between the institutes and their corresponding Ids, at my first thought was doing something like `=if(A2 = 81, "Institute example 1", "")`, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do with it you could use VLOOKUP. I have created this sample [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QZwUUES3gQX-c04KzGMJvnVrlJKkbkkpn6DfAsfSLtU/edit?usp=sharing) where you can just introduce the name of the institution and get the ID based on the name, so that would create the relation between them.

The formula I used in this sample spreadsheet is:

```
= VLOOKUP(G3,B4:D8,3,FALSE)
```

[image]

Ref:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: Actually this was what I need thanks